# Predicting next week incidents using text analysis on incident reports

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, data-science

I want to do a project but I'm not sure if it's really viable neither which path I should take to try and solve this.

I have a dataset with numerous incidents from different places and their risk classification. For example:

```
Incident: "John stumbled and fell down the stairs"

Risk: Severe

Warehouse: A

Date: 2020-07-11

---

Incident: "Mary left the door open"

Risk: Low

Warehouse: B

Date: 2020-07-10
```

My idea is to compile the incidents by warehouse by week and give a probability of incidents happening in each warehouse for every risk.

```
Warehouse A

Probability of low risk incidents next week: 60%

Probability of severe risk incidents next week: 30%
```

But I'm not really sure how to get around this problem. It's not really text classification because I know the classification of every report (risk). Is there a way to use this dataset and get any prediction for the next week?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think this incidents are not correlated, so it should be hard to find an useful pattern.
That problem can be thought as a regression problem, where the probability of accidents is what you want the model to predict. Consider using a Recurrent Neural Network (RNN) that are useful for time-series problems.